# CoreBluetooth Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, core-bluetooth

I followed all steps for using CoreBluetooth correctly but Xcode keeps telling me the following thing:

> Objective-C method
>   'centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:'
>   provided by method
>   'centralManager(*:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:)'
>   conflicts with optional requirement method
>   'centralManager(*:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:)' in
>   protocol 'CBCentralManagerDelegate'

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

var centralManager:CBCentralManager!
var blueToothReady = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startUpCentralManager()
}

func startUpCentralManager() {
    print("Initializing central manager")
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

func discoverDevices() {
    print("discovering devices")
    centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
    print("Discovered \(peripheral.name)")
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    print("checking state")
    switch (central.state) {
    case .PoweredOff:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")

    case .PoweredOn:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
        blueToothReady = true;

    case .Resetting:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting")

    case .Unauthorized:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized")

    case .Unknown:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");

    case .Unsupported:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");

    }
    if blueToothReady {
        discoverDevices()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: I assume you need to add "override" to the method declaration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576864/diddiscoverperipheral-fail-to-build-error ?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters changed from implicitly unwrapped optionals (e.g., CBCentralManager!) to normal non-optionals (e.g., CBCentralManager - with no !).

The function signature should look like this (Xcode 7.1, Swift 2.1) -

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
```